# TortoiseSVN icon to denote "Unchanged, and out of date" state?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was reading through the 1.6.X version of the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.pdf) and I noticed on page 32 (of the PDF) that SVN can tell when a file is unchanged but out of date with respect to the repository.  Does the latest version TortoiseSVN have a way to iconify a file/directory in this state?  We are on 1.4.X and this feature would be just one more reason to justify the upgrade to management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing that can be determined locally, so there is no icon overlay. However, you can see this in the "Check for modifications" dialog *after* you clicked "Check repository".

One could argue that if you click that button, that information should be cached and reflected by the icon, but with a limited number of icon overlays and me never having clicked that button I personally consider such a feature of little use.

Comment: Oh, by the way: Locking and especially Merge Tracking were some of the reasons why we upgraded recently.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping that TortoiseSVN had some sort of background daemon that could periodically query the repository for this information.  I know that it spawns a daemon to query the local drives for icon updates.